# How to use mod_rewrite to rewrite dynamic url for search?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a webshop where there is a search field. When I search I am forwarded to a link looking like this:

webshopdomain.com/index.php?route=product/search&keyword=**my search phrase**

(well, it's more like this: webshopdomain.com/index.php?route=product/search&keyword=my%20search%20phrase )

**What do I need to put in htaccess to make this url : webshopdomain.com/search/my%20search%20phrase** show the content of the above url?

I have been playing around with this tool ( http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php ) , but haven't understood how to just grab the search phrase and put that into a static url.

I have also been googling, but in lack of the correct wording, I haven't found the answer.

Thanks :-)

EDIT:

Can I use this? (Just thought out, gonna test...)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule search/(.*) index.php?route=product/search&keyword=$1
RewriteRule search/(.*)/ index.php?route=product/search&keyword=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite simple, but had to rearrange the htaccess file itself.

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$  index.php\?route=product/search&keyword=$1

Answer (score 0):

To avoid recursion, you need to look at the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php\?route=product/search&keyword=([^&\ ]*)&*([^\ ]+)?
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /search/%1?%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you :-) I tried this, but it didn't seam to work. Is it possible to let the whole index.php?route=product/search&keyword= be one part of the url, and then everything after = be ONE argument that is put inside the new url?